# Fatal error: Can't find core file. CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

After migrating to CakePHP 2.0, I uploaded it to my server and got these creepy errors.

Warning: include(/home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/app/Config/core.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 75

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/app/Config/core.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/lib:.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 75

Fatal error: Can't find application core file. Please create /home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/app/Config/core.php, and make sure it is readable by PHP. in /home/content/32/11382832/html/shafiullah/hs/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `webroot/index.php`

```
//some code ... 
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
//some code ... 

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    if (!include(ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'lib/Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
}
```

And rename your views to "View", layouts to "Layouts" and config to "Config"